# How can I add auth into a payload .bin file?

Tags: c++, ps4

How can I add auth into a payload .bin file for PS4 in c++?
I want to add a key login auth into my .bin file.

Comment: Your question and its context is unclear. Please edit the question and include the necessary details.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.